# Dijkstra con nodo intermedio

Tags: java

Tengo este algoritmo de dijkstra que lo que hace es calcular la distancia más corta entre dos ciudades teniendo que pasar previamente por una ciudad intermedia, por ejemplo, tengo que ir desde ALmería a Barcelona teniendo que pasar por Madrid, sería Almería -> Granada -> Jaen -> Madrid -> Zaragoza -> Barcelona.

Mi idea es calcular por un lado la distancia entre el nodo origen y el nodo intermedio, y por otro lado la distancia entre el nodoIntermedio y el destino, una vez calculadas ambas distancias, el algoritmo devolvería la suma de ambas distancias. Este es el algoritmo que tengo:

```html
public static class Arista implements Comparable<Arista>{
        String fuente, dest;
        int peso;

        public Arista(String fuente, String dest, int peso) {
            this.fuente = fuente;
            this.dest = dest;
            this.peso = peso;
        }

        public int compareTo(Arista otraArista) {
            if (this.peso < otraArista.peso) {
                return -1;
            } else if (this.peso == otraArista.peso) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public static class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
        
        String id;
        int distancia;

        public Vertex(String id, int distancia) {
            this.id = id;
            this.distancia = distancia;
        }

        public int compareTo(Vertex otro) {
            if (this.distancia < otro.distancia) {
                return -1;
            } else if (this.distancia > otro.distancia) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }


    public static int dijkstra(TreeMap<String, Vertex> vertices, TreeSet<Arista> aristas, String fuente, String destino, String intermedio) {
        TreeMap<String, Integer> distancia = new TreeMap<>(); 
        TreeMap<String, Vertex> predecesor = new TreeMap<>(); 
        TreeSet<String> visitados = new TreeSet<>(); 
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> cola = new PriorityQueue<>(); 

        for (String v : vertices.keySet()) {
            distancia.put(v, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            predecesor.put(v, null);
        }

        distancia.put(fuente, 0);
        cola.offer(new Vertex(fuente, 0));

        while (!cola.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex v = cola.poll();
            String u = v.id;

            if (visitados.contains(u)) {
                continue;
            }

            visitados.add(u);
            
            if (u.equals(intermedio)) {
                break;
            }

            for (Arista a : aristas) {
                String d1 = null;
                if (a.fuente.equals(u)) {
                    d1 = a.dest;
                } else if (a.dest.equals(u)) {
                    d1 = a.fuente;
                } else {
                    continue; 
                }

                int peso = a.peso;

                int distanciaIntermedio = distancia.get(u) + peso;

              
                if (distanciaIntermedio < distancia.get(d1)) {
                    distancia.put(d1, distanciaIntermedio);
                    predecesor.put(d1, vertices.get(u));

                    cola.offer(new Vertex(d1, distanciaIntermedio));
                }
            }
        }
        
        int distanciaI = distancia.get(intermedio);
        
        TreeMap<String, Integer> distancia2 = new TreeMap<>(); // TreeMap para almacenar las distancias minimas desde la fuente
        TreeMap<String, Vertex> predecesor2 = new TreeMap<>(); // TreeMap para almacenar los predecesores
        TreeSet<String> visitados2 = new TreeSet<>(); // TreeSet para marcar los nodos visitados
      

        for (String v : vertices.keySet()) {
            distancia2.put(v, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            predecesor2.put(v, null);
        }

        distancia2.put(intermedio, 0);
        cola.offer(new Vertex(intermedio, 0));

        while (!cola.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex v = cola.poll();
            String u = v.id;

            if (visitados2.contains(u)) {
                continue;
            }

            visitados2.add(u);
            
            if (u.equals(destino)) {
                break;
            }

            for (Arista a : aristas) {
                String d2 = null;
                if (a.fuente.equals(u)) {
                    d2 = a.dest;
                } else if (a.dest.equals(u)) {
                    d2 = a.fuente;
                } else {
                    continue; 
                }
                int peso = a.peso;

                
                int distanciaTotal = distancia.get(u) + peso;

                
                if (distanciaTotal < distancia.get(d2)) {
                    distancia.put(d2, distanciaTotal);
                    predecesor.put(d2, vertices.get(u));

                   
                    cola.offer(new Vertex(d2, distanciaTotal));
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        if (predecesor.get(destino) == null) {
            System.out.println("No se encontró un camino desde " + fuente + " hasta " + destino);
            return -1;
        }

        
        String camino = "";
        Vertex v = vertices.get(intermedio);
        while (v != null) {
            camino = " -> " + v.id + camino;
            v = predecesor.get(v.id);
        }
        String camino2 = "";
        Vertex v2 = vertices.get(destino);
        while (v2 != null) {
            camino2 = " -> " + v2.id + camino2;
            v2 = predecesor2.get(v2.id);
        }
        System.out.println("Camino más corto desde " + fuente + " hasta " + destino + " pasando por " + intermedio + " es: " + fuente + camino + camino2);
        int distanciaTotal = distanciaI + distancia.get(destino);
        return distanciaTotal;
    }
```

El test que trato de ejecutar es el siguiente:

```html
@Test
    public void testDijkstra() {
         
        // Creamos los vertices
        TreeMap<String, Vertex> vertices = new TreeMap<>();
        vertices.put("Almeria", new Vertex("Almeria", 0));
        vertices.put("Granada", new Vertex("Granada", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Cadiz", new Vertex("Cadiz", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Huelva", new Vertex("Huelva", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Sevilla", new Vertex("Sevilla", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Jaen", new Vertex("Jaen", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Murcia", new Vertex("Murcia", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Caceres", new Vertex("Caceres", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Badajoz", new Vertex("Badajoz", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Albacete", new Vertex("Albacete", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Valencia", new Vertex("Valencia", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Madrid", new Vertex("Madrid", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Barcelona", new Vertex("Barcelona", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Gerona", new Vertex("Gerona", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Lerida", new Vertex("Lerida", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Zaragoza", new Vertex("Zaragoza", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Bilbao", new Vertex("Bilbao", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Oviedo", new Vertex("Oviedo", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Valladolid", new Vertex("Valladolid", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Vigo", new Vertex("Vigo", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Corunya", new Vertex("Corunya", Integer.MAX_VALUE));

        // Creamos las aristas
        TreeSet<Arista> aristas = new TreeSet<>();
        aristas.add(new Arista("Almeria", "Granada", 173));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Almeria", "Murcia", 224));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Granada", "Murcia", 278));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Granada", "Jaen", 99));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Granada", "Sevilla", 256));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Cadiz", "Sevilla", 125));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Huelva", "Sevilla", 92));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Huelva", "Badajoz", 234));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Sevilla", "Jaen", 242));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Jaen", "Madrid", 335));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Murcia", "Albacete", 150));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Murcia", "Valencia", 241));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Caceres", "Badajoz", 90));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Badajoz", "Madrid", 403));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Albacete", "Valencia", 191));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Albacete", "Madrid", 251));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Valencia", "Barcelona", 349));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Madrid", "Zaragoza", 325));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Madrid", "Bilbao", 395));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Madrid", "Valladolid", 193));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Barcelona", "Zaragoza", 296));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Barcelona", "Gerona", 100));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Gerona", "Lerida", 222));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Zaragoza", "Bilbao", 324));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Bilbao", "Valladolid", 280));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Bilbao", "Oviedo", 304));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Valladolid", "Vigo", 356));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Valladolid", "Corunya", 455));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Vigo", "Corunya", 171));
        
        int distancia = Dijkstra.dijkstra(vertices, aristas, "Almeria", "Sevilla", "Granada");
        int distancia2 = Dijkstra.dijkstra(vertices, aristas, "Almeria", "Lerida", "Madrid");
        
        assertEquals(429, distancia);
        assertEquals(1550, distancia2);
    }
```

No sé cuál podría ser el error.

Comment: Hola! Faltó que indiques cuál es el problema. ¿Por qué dices que hay un error?

Comment: revisa como crear un [mcve]